# How can i implement axios delete request for a specific Item?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using axios in ReactJs and I send a DELETE request to my server.

Here is my code:

```
axios
.delete(`${REACT_API_URL}/news/${id}`, {
                headers: { "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token") },
            })
            .then(res => console.log(res))
```

And Here is my server code:

```
const getNewsByIdAndDelete = async (req, res) => {
    const token = req.headers["x-access-token"];
    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "secret");
        await News.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
        res.json({ status: "success" });
    }
```

I am not getting any response from the server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in server you get the  `req.params.id` ??

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
:id
```

to your endpoint, you call getNewsByIdAndDelete from

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).